#  return view, but also jump to div

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I've got a page with some server side validation. It works, in that on a server validation failure it displays the same page, with a box with the validation errors above the form where the data was input.

My problem is that there is a whole bunch of other stuff at the top of the page, so the user isn't directed to the error box, in fact it could be off screen. The errors are in a div #server_errors. What I want is to tell the controller to return the view, but jump to the errors section, the same as appending  #server_errors to the url.

the controller returns like this:

```
public ActionResult ChangeRiskCategory(Guid id)
{
    //...
    //call server side method,  handle errors
    //...
    return View("ChangeRiskCategory", changeRiskCategoryModel);
}
```

and I can't see a way to inject the div id into the view at this point. I can see validating client side would solve this problem but it needs to work without js enabled so I think that rules that out.

Comment: Well, I could see using JS on the client side to auto-scroll to the error summary or the first error in the form, but since that all requires JavaScript it won't work with JS disabled. The only way to get the hash tag (#server_errors ) in the URL is to do a redirect  but even that has its limitations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
public ActionResult ChangeRiskCategory(Guid id, bool error = false)
{
    //...
    //call server side method,  handle errors
    //...
    if (!error && !ModelState.IsValid /*or other way of working out the error will be displayed*/)
    {
        return Redirect(Url.Action("ChangeRiskCategory") + "?id=" + id + "&error=true#server_error");
    }
    return View("ChangeRiskCategory", changeRiskCategoryModel);

}
```

(The "error" parameter is to stop it endlessly redirecting)

If you change your mind about using javascript you could simply emit:

```
location.href='#server_errors';
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this could result in your validation logic and page load being run twice for each failure, so while this solution answers the question I'd advise only using it in a "all else fails" situation as it's a lot less efficient. Consider detecting if JS is disabled and only do the server-side redirect in this instance to mitigate this.

Answer (score 1):

What about passing the div id as a property of the ViewModel to the View? Then you can do whatever you want with it in Javascript in the view. After all, the ViewModel represents the data and state of the View.

Comment: Thanks Dante, Ideally I'm looking for something that will work without js though.

Comment: Didn't notice that part, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Use model based validation and have you view look something like this

```
@model SampleApplication.Models.BasicDemoModel

<form id="AjaxForm" action="/">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name)</td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name, "*")
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Email)</td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Email, "*")
            </td>
        </tr>
        @{
            Html.RenderPartial("Address", Model);
        }
    </table>
    @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.Message))
    {
        <h2>@Model.Message</h2>
    }
    @if (!ViewContext.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
    }
    <input type="submit" title="Submit Form" onclick="PostFormWithAjax();return false;" />
</form>
```

if you need extra validation messages you can just add it to the more state like this

```
public ActionResult ChangeRiskCategory(Guid id)
{
    //...
    //call server side method,  handle errors
    //...
    ModelState.AddModelError("MyInput","This isn't Right");
    return View("ChangeRiskCategory", changeRiskCategoryModel);
 }
```